# Solve of the differential equation $\left(3y^2+x^2+x+2y+1\right)\cdot y'+2xy+y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have some problem. 
There is an equation:
$$\left(3y^2+x^2+x+2y+1\right)\cdot y'+2xy+y=0$$
Open brackets. 
$$3y^2dy+x^2dy+2xdx y+xdy +ydx +2ydy+dy=0$$
But what to do, tell me, please?

I saw this a duplicate:

[Find the general solution of the differential equation $\left(3y^2+x^2+x+2y+1\right)\cdot y'+2xy+y=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284964/find-the-general-solution-of-the-differential-equation-left3y2x2x2y1-ri/1284981#1284981)

But he resolved properly, I ask to prompt more options.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284964/find-the-general-solution-of-the-differential-equation-left3y2x2x2y1-ri/1284981#1284981 , this is duplicate.

Comment: I have seen, but there decided incorrectly.

Comment: this equation has an ugly solution

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner :DD

Answer (score 2):

Anyway here's a solution, since you are asking for intermediate steps.

$3y^2dy+x^2dy+2xdx y+xdy +ydx +2ydy+dy=0$

$\color{blue}{\overbrace{3y^2dy+2ydy+dy}}+\color{red}{\underbrace{x^2dy +2xdxy}} + \color{green}{\overbrace{xdy + ydx}}=0$

Notice the expression coloured, They can be written as

$\color{blue}{3y^2dy+2ydy+dy=d(y^3+y^2+y)}$

$\color{red}{x^2dy +2xdxy=d(x^2y)}$

$\color{green}{xdy + ydx=d(xy)}$

Substituting and using linearity of derivative.

$d(y^3+y^2+y+x^2y+xy)=0$

Now integrate.

Comment: And this solution is same as given in link. And is correct.

Comment: I agree, but I understand now how it got there.
Or you can decide to end?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand how this is different but in general it is extremely useful to be able to recognize these things:

$$y^2y'=\frac{(y^3)'}{3}$$

$$yy'=\frac{(y^2)'}{2}$$

$$xy'+y=(xy)'$$

These come up all the time.

Answer (score 0):

ops . a simple way to solve this problem! this Differential equation is exact!

$(3y^2+x^2+x+2y+1)dy+(2xy+y)dx=0$

$\frac{\partial M(x,y)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N(x,y)}{\partial x}=2x+1$

$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=N(x,y)$

$f(x,y)={\int (3y^2+x^2+x+2y+1)dy}+h(x)$

$f(x,y)=y^3+yx^2+xy+y^2+y+h(x)$

$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=M(x,y)$

$2xy+y+h'(x)=2xy+y$

$h'(x)=0$ , $h(x)=c$

$$f(x,y)=y^3+yx^2+xy+y^2+y=C$$